# Plots get curropted when rendering HTML using flask Tempelate

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, jinja2

I am trying to output my results by putting the graphs in an HTML Template.

I have a function for making my plots :

```
def Density(**some arguments to get data)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(500/96,500/96), dpi=96)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    sns.distplot(#ploting worksfine )

    #so here is the fun part
    ByteImage = ByteIO()
    plt.close()
    plt.clf()
    FigureCanvasAgg(fig).print_png(BytesImage)
    ByteImage.seek(0)

    return ByteImage
```

and in Flask :

```
@app.route('/plot/<group>', methods=['GET'])
def plot(group):

    BytesImage = Density(splitDataframe(df_dataset,group,1),'Y(C2), %',group)

    return send_file(BytesImage, attachment_filename = 'plot'+str(group)+'.png', mimetype = 'image/png')
```

and I also have another part in flask run file that renders the HTML

```
@app.route('/TreePlot')
    def buildPage():
        data = [{'divisions': ['1a', '1b'], 'show': [True, True], 'width': [8, 92]}]
        return render_template('Template.html', data=data)
```

and the HTML Template is :

```
{% for items in data %}
        <div class="levels" style="width: 100%">
            {% for groupnumber in range(items.divisions|length)%} {% if items.show[groupnumber] == True %}
            <div class="groups" style="width: {{items.width[groupnumber]}}%">
                <div class="content"> {{items.divisions[groupnumber]}} </div>
                <img src="http://localhost:8080/plot/{{items.divisions[groupnumber]}}" />
            </div>
            {% else %}
            <div class="groups" style="width: {{items.width[groupnumber]}}%">
                <div class="content-empty"> </div>
            </div>
            {% endif %} {% endfor %}
        </diV>
        {% endfor %}
```

so when I call http://127.0.0.1:8080/plot/3a
I get a nice rendered plot :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlAA3.png)

but when calling :
http://127.0.0.1:8080/TreePlot

all the plots are plotted on top of each other and it makes no sense why:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nEwR.png)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

In that snippet, nothing connects `plt` with `ByteImage`. Try adding something like this:

```
ByteImage = ByteIO()
plt.savefig(ByteImage)  # << add this
plt.close()
plt.clf()
ByteImage.seek(0)

return ByteImage
```

I have a working toy example [here](https://github.com/davewsmith/play/blob/master/matplotlib-flask/app.py) that shows some additional parts you might need.

Comment: it is still not working , I also tried to change seaborn for simple matplotlib, but I still get plots stacked over each other

Comment: Change `plt.savefig` to `fig.savefig`, and do it before `plt.close()`.